# How to block HTML elements by text they contain?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, blocking, adblock, web-filtering

I'm looking for a way to hide particular text fragments in a browser—all those news about buzzwords of the day. The idea is to hide HTML elements whose inner text contains certain keywords.

I've written a toy Chrome extension that hides text containing words from a closed-ended list. Now I'm looking for a more extensive solution that supports adding/removing words, and, perhaps, smarter filtering.

I haven't found a Chrome extension like this.

Now I have the usual suspects. AdBlock and uBlock. They remove ads by URL. Can they hide elements by inner text?

Or maybe better solutions exist?

Answer (score 1):

### CustomBlocker

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/customblocker/elnfhbjabfcepfnaeoehffgmifcfjlha

Not uBlock, but it claims to hide objects with keywords:

> - Block tweets with specific hashtags, URL or keywords on Twitter
> - Hide tweets posted by specific apps on Twitter
> - Mute reviews written by specific users on Amazon or other shopping sites
> - Block comments which contain unpleasant or offensive words or tags on Facebook
> - Remove results of specific domains from Google search results
> - Filter videos by titles on YouTube
> - Make ads invisible even if they are displayed in styles of "normal" posts

Answer (score 1):

I think jdwolf meant to refer to `:-abp-contains()` so here's an example filter which on example.com hides an element `<foo class="bar">` that contains the text `baz`:

`example.com#?#foo.bar:-abp-contains(baz)`

You can find more examples in [EasyList](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6069) by searching for `:-abp-contains(`. I also created a ticket (see [#6069](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6069)) to create some official documentation for this feature under [adblockplus.org/filters](https://adblockplus.org/filters#elemhide-emulation).

Comment: These days you can use `:has-text()`, which is the exact same thing as `:-abp-contains()` (it's an alias)